# Azure SQL server error Statement 'RECEIVE MSG' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, sqldependency

I have used SQLdependency with SignalR to show alerts to users.. The code is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<AlertInfo> GetData(long UserId)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yafnet"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [AlertID],[AlertNote],[AlertDetails],[AlertDate],[Location]
      FROM [dbo].[Alerts] where [UserID]=" + UserId + " AND [IsViewed]=0", connection))
        {
            // Make sure the command object does not already have
            // a notification object associated with it.
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yafnet"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yafnet"].ConnectionString);

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                    .Select(x => new AlertInfo()
                    {
                        AlertID = x.GetInt64(0),
                        AlertNote = x.GetString(1),
                        AlertDetails = x.GetString(2),
                        AlertDate = x.GetDateTime(3),
                        Location = x.GetString(4)
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine on localhost. But after uploading to Azure server, this method throws the following error:

> Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Statement 'RECEIVE MSG' is not supported
>    in this version of SQL Server.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","StackTrace":"
>   \r\nServer stack trace: \r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception
>   , Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your SQL Server database must have `is_broker_enabled = 1`.
You need to check whether it's enabled or not.

To verify this, use the command `SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases`.
If your database shows result "1" it's okay and if "0" then you must enable it using this command `ALTER DATABASE yourdb SET ENABLE_BROKER`.

But the bad news is Azure SQL database shows it enabled but it no longer supports `is_broker_enabled`.

To do this, you need to install the full instance of SQL Server to Azure VM.